# Restsharp 107.x ExecuteAsync upload file to uploadsession fails (GraphAPI Sharepoint), 106.x does work

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

I have my below code which works proper on 106.15, I get a succesfull status. Project is Visual Studio 2022 (.Net 4.8)

```
accessToken = GetAccessToken()
Dim rRequest As RestRequest
Dim rClient As RestClient
Dim rResponse As RestResponse

Try
    Dim data() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(fileSource)
    
    rClient = New RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0")
    rRequest = New RestRequest(uploadURL, Method.Put)

    rRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken)
    rRequest.AddHeader("Content-Range", New ContentRangeHeaderValue(0, data.Length - 1, data.Length).ToString)
    rRequest.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length)
    rRequest.AddParameter("application/binary", data, ParameterType.RequestBody)

    rResponse = Await rClient.ExecuteAsync(rRequest)
```

When I execute the code on 107.15 it fails with the following error : There was an error sending the request (translated from dutch)

Any idea what could be wrong or should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 108.0.1 fixes the issue, it is working now.

[This commit from 03 Mar 22](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/a7d2662ef95269fab1e6dac2ef2ad3003c5c1e85) shows the fix.

Comment: IMO, the information that a new version fixes an issue is an answer and also possibly helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#uploading-files).

Don't use this:

```
rRequest.AddHeader("Content-Range", New ContentRangeHeaderValue(0, data.Length - 1, data.Length).ToString)
rRequest.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length)
rRequest.AddParameter("application/binary", data, ParameterType.RequestBody)
```

use `AddFile` instead.

You can still add the `Content-Range` header manually using `AddHeader`. As you aren't uploading the file (although you kind of do), you might not the file name to be there. In that case, you can try this:

```
rRequest
    .AddBody(data)
    .AddHeader("Content-Range", New ContentRangeHeaderValue(0, data.Length - 1, data.Length).ToString())
```

When `AddBody` gets a byte array, it will use the `application/binary` content type, and set the length correctly.

Comment: Thank you Alexey, I read the documentation ofcourse before posting ;-). But AddFile does not work with the Graph API when using an upload session, the content-range header and content-length are required headers, as you can upload a file fully or parts, if they are not there then it always nag : ("{""error"":{""code"":""invalidRequest"",""message"":""The Content-Range header is missing or malformed.""}}") https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0 shows how to do it, which does work in 106.15. Downgrade to 106.15 or is it fixable?

Comment: The `Content-Range` header is only required if you upload a part of the file. But your code uploads the whole thing, it's really weird that it's failing.

Comment: The thing is that RestSharp uses `StreamContent` that _supposes_ to set all the correct headers. But again, the `Content-Range` header must not be a required header.

Comment: If i do only the .addbody and .addheader(Content-Range it gives this : "{""error"":{""code"":""invalidRequest"",""message"":""The Content-Range header length does not match the provided number of bytes.""}}". Is there any trick to check the set length?

Comment: RestSharp sets the length properly, I am not sure what happens. You can use requestbin.com and send your requests there both using RS 106 and 107 to see the difference in headers. It would give you a better idea about what's going on.

Comment: When using your body method on 107.3, it gives the length 26130, it should be 19594. On 106.15 that method crashes

Comment: With the .addfile method the length is : 19820 (106.15)

Comment: With the .addfile method the length is : 19802 (107.3), 19802 is no typo

Comment: Thanx for the tip of requestbin, really handy :-)

Comment: What's the actual file length then?

Comment: On Windows Command Prompt it show 19.594 bytes, Getting the length of the bytes in VB .Net also gives 19594